Check if floats appear before the page where they are first referred
In the 2017 I asked: Get the "exact" page of a \ref command in .log or .aux files.
I still need to check if a float appears before the page where that float is first referred. I have a script that works fine with standard \label/\ref commands but I'm in trouble with cleveref commands. (Unfortunately, cleveref's poorman option has too often proven to be ineffective, although being able to convert cleveref's commands to "standard" ones would solve most of my problems.)
Is there any package or tool that can help me with this? Up to now my approach has been based on LaTeX, using the .aux file. Should I perhaps try to check directly on the .pdf file?
Note added. In this post, I believed I was asking if there exists a specific package or even a different approach (for example, by analyzing the .pdf) to address my issue. In another post (Patching \cref and \Cref to write additional information to the .aux file), however, I asked for more specific help to tackle the problem using methods I had already dealt with in the past. From my point of view, the two questions are related but still different and separate. I'm sorry if I upset anyone.

You might want to take a look at zref-check. See the manual though about the method used for this task and its limitations.

... "but I'm in trouble with cleveref commands"; I assume that's because cleveref's commands can take multiple inputs, needn't be associated with one particular counter, and needn't be sorted in any way, right? If the \cref commands of interest happen to take a single input, I suppose you could temporarily replace the \cref commands with \ref commands and then run your checker script.

@Mico unfortunately, such temporary replacement would have unpredictable effects on the layout, thus rendering the check result unreliable.

you could use \usepackage{flafter} then floats never float backwards so floats never appear before their first reference so long as you enter them in the source at the point of that reference.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you, but it's not a practical solution for me. My job involves standardizing the layout of scientific articles (I do not produce them), and the condition of not having floats before their references isn't strictly obligatory. I need a minimum level of flexibility (though I still need to perform this check).

OK no poblem, I thought it was worth a mention, as you didn't say what you would do if the check failed, if it was a hard error that avoids it but as you say if you may want to allow it in some cases, it doesn't help.

@gusbrs I quickly read through the manual, but it's not clear to me whether your package also works with the standard hyperref commands and if cleveref is supported. Additionally, I couldn't find any usage examples relevant to my case. I simply need to test whether a float appears on a page before its first reference in the text, without considering the accompanying text of the reference. Is this type of check supported for hyperref and cleveref?

@Gabriele zref-check allows you to test if an arbitrary piece of your document, e.g. a reference command, occurs before or after a given label. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if that's what you want, it may be useful. It integrates well with zref-clever and can easily be made to work with standard \labels, and thus cleveref, by adding a \zlabel to the label hook. To check if a given reference occurs after a figure you could use something like (with zref-clever) \zcref[check=after]{fig:1} or (with cleveref) \zcheck[after]{fig:1}{\cref{fig:1}}.

@gusbrs I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use this package. Where can I find a MWE? Do you think it would be appropriate for me to open a dedicated issue to clarify my doubts? In particular, I can't figure out if \zcheck should be used in the preamble or if it's a command that not only performs the test but also affects the layout. I'm only interested in the test. I do NOT want to modify the text.

@Gabriele \zcheck is a document command which allows you to test the relative position (in a number of different relations) of your document with respect to label(s) in the document. In particular, it has a check which tests if it occurs before or after the label. If I understand your use case, you'd want something like \documentclass{article} \usepackage{zref-clever,zref-check,hyperref} \begin{document} \zcref[check=after]{fig:1} \begin{figure}[t] Figure \caption{Figure 1} \label{fig:1} \end{figure} \end{document}. [...]

[...] This document generates a warning Package zref-check Warning: Check failed on line 4. Failed check 'after' for label 'fig:1' on page 1. to warn you that the relation between the label and the reference you were assuming does not hold.

@gusbrs Ok, Thank you, now it's clear to me. Thank you. I was thinking of temporarily redefining (not replacing in the text) some macros (such as \ref, \cref, \Cref, etc.) like this: \cref{label} --> \zcheck[after]{label}{\cref{label}}, but perhaps it's not the best approach. This is because I would get warnings related to other non-float LaTeX objects, and also because it would exclude (or perhaps cause an error for) the case \cref{label1,label2}.

@Gabriele Yes, that'd be a bad idea, and the reason is the one you mentioned. zref-check presumes you specify in your document the checks you want performed. A wholesale redefinition of the sort would make the package of very little use, with the real intended warnings drowned amid false ones...

Cross-posted updated question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714877/. (Is 'cross-posted' the right word when it is the same site?)
