Patching \cref and \Cref to write additional information to the .aux file
I need to patch the macros \cref and \Cref so that when used like this:
\cref{label1,label2,label3}

besides generating the normal layout in the document, they write something like this to the .aux (or .log) file:
"label1" referred on page N
"label2" referred on page N
"label3" referred on page N

where "N" corresponds to the page number in which the \cref macro is used.
This, combined with the information regarding the \label macro in the .aux file, is needed to test whether figures and tables appear in the document on a page preceding their citation in the text. (At the moment, I am able to do this for the \ref macro using the technique described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365954/33634).
Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient knowledge of LaTeX to implement this idea.
Could you at least give me some suggestions on:

What to use to patch (maybe \patchcmd?) the \cref macro (assuming it's possible)
How to split the argument of \cref since it accepts multiple labels separated by commas
How to obtain the page number in which the macro is used

I recognize that my question may be a bit too complex, but I hope you can help me.
Edit. I tried to adapt the solution proposed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365937/33634
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcounter{crefusage}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}

\let\oldcref\cref
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{{\refstepcounter{crefusage}\label{crefusage:\thecrefusage}\oldcref{#1}\typeout{::#1:: referred on page \getpagerefnumber{crefusage:\thecrefusage}}}}
\robustify\cref
\let\oldCref\Cref
\renewcommand{\Cref}[1]{{\refstepcounter{crefusage}\label{crefusage:\thecrefusage}\oldCref{#1}\typeout{::#1:: referred on page \getpagerefnumber{crefusage:\thecrefusage}}}}
\robustify\Cref

}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\clearpage

\ref{somefigure}
\cref{somefigure}

\section{First section}\label{firstsec}

\blindtext[5]
\Cref{somefigure}

\blindtext[45]
\cref{somefigure,someotherfigure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some figure\cref{someotherfigure}}\label{somefigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Some other figure\cref{somefigure}}\label{someotherfigure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[50]

\cref{somefigure}
\section{Second section}\label{secondsec}

\end{document}

In the log file I get:
::somefigure:: referred on page 4
::somefigure:: referred on page 5
[4]
::somefigure,someotherfigure:: referred on page 15
[5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13]
::someotherfigure:: referred on page 0
::someotherfigure:: referred on page 15
[14]
::somefigure:: referred on page 0
::somefigure:: referred on page 15
[15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25]
::somefigure:: referred on page 26
[26] (./test.aux) )

The ::somefigure,someotherfigure:: referred on page 15 generated by \cref{somefigure,someotherfigure} is not a problem but I'd like to avoid ::somefigure:: referred on page 0 generated by the subcaption package.
Since my intention is only to perform a check, I used this complex latexmk command to generate exclusively the auxiliary files without modifying the original file, that is, without actually writing anything in the preamble:

latexmk -pdf
-usepretex='\RequirePackage{etoolbox}\newcounter{crefusage}\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}\let\oldcref\cref\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{{\refstepcounter{crefusage}\label{crefusage:\thecrefusage}\oldcref{#1}\typeout{::#1::
referred on page
\getpagerefnumber{crefusage:\thecrefusage}}}}\robustify\cref\let\oldCref\Cref\renewcommand{\Cref}[1]{{\refstepcounter{crefusage}\label{crefusage:\thecrefusage}\oldCref{#1}\typeout{::#1::
referred on page
\getpagerefnumber{crefusage:\thecrefusage}}}}\robustify\Cref}\makeatother'
-pdflatex='export max_print_line=1000; touch %D; pdflatex -draftmode %O %P' -output-directory=/tmp -jobname=floatsCrefPosCheck test.tex

I have no idea if this solution is robust and reliable. I hope you can help me understand and find the best solution.
Note added. In a previous post (Check if floats appear before the page where they are first referred), I believed I was asking if there exists a specific package or even a different approach (for example, by analyzing the .pdf) to address my issue. In this post, however, I asked for more specific help to tackle the problem using methods I had already dealt with in the past. From my point of view, the two questions are related but still different and separate. I'm sorry if I upset anyone.

I have cleaned up comments here

@JosephWright Thank you very much. If I could, I would have done it myself.
